# Possible to trick AWS SDK `defaultProvider` function with a custom environment variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, netlify, netlify-function

Problem: Netlify serverless functions run on AWS Lambda. So `AWS_` is a reserved prefix in Netlify, meaning I can't use e.g. `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` for my own environment var that I set in the Netlify admin panel.

But the only way I have been auble to authenticate Nodemailer with AWS SES (the email service) is with `@aws/aws-sdk` and its `defaultProvider` function that requires `process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` – spelled exactly like that:

```
import 'dotenv/config'
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'
import aws from '@aws-sdk/client-ses'
import { defaultProvider } from '@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node'

const ses = new aws.SES({
  apiVersion: '2019-09-29',
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  defaultProvider,
  rateLimit: 1
})

const sesTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ SES: { ses, aws } })
```

When building the function locally with the Netlify CLI, emails are sent.

It fails with 403 and `InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid` in the live Netlify environment.

Netlify doesn't have a solution afaik, but mention in a forum post that **custom env variables in AWS is a thing**. I haven't been able to find anything in searches (they didn't provide any links). The AWS docs are pretty unhelpful as always :/

**So the question is, how can this be done?**

I thought I was clever when I tried the following, but setting the vars just before creating the SES Transport apparently doesn't help:

```
  // Trick Netlify reserved env vars:

  process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID
  process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY

  console.log('AWS access key id ', process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) // Logs the correct key!
  console.log('AWS sec key ', process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ) // Logs the correct
```

Comment: In [previous versions of the NodeJS AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html) you could do something like `ses = new aws.SES({accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY});` This option is completely missing from the version 3 SDK documentation as far as I can tell. I would suggest trying that though, they may have just removed it from the documentation to discourage people that were using hard-coded credentials inside client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkB that would make complete sense. But it fails in the same way as before. I'm wondering if there could be more to it, like a geographical region mismatch (me in Europe, Netlify CDN in some other location, AWS region set to EU-west). I guess I won't find out until I hardcode the credentials into my script ...

Comment: Regions being different shouldn't matter at all. It's very common to call SES in a different region because it's only available in a few regions.

Comment: How do you plan to hard-code the credentials into your script? If you know how to do that, then specifying them as custom environment variables should be trivial.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it wouldn't make any difference from using my custom named env vars.